# Azure logic app - Transform to XML - MapNotReady

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to translate an X12 edi message using a map created in VS2015, but I get the following error;

MapNotReady. The map '' is still being processed. Please try again later.

Running the input in VS2015 I get the correct result, but not using Azure Logic Apps

Comment: You are uploading the generated xslt, correct?

Comment: @Johns-305 yup, uploading the xslt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this issue by creating a new `Integration account` in a new `Resource Group` and different `Location`.

Looks like a bug in Azure, will log call with MS

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue after deploying a logic app using ARM template.

What was I doing?

1. In deploy powershell, I was creating integration account and adding schemas and maps.
2. Deploying logic app using ARM template.

Immediately after deployment, I tried to execute the logic app. At that point, I received  **MapNotReady** exception in transform action.

However after 10 minutes when I retried the message again, the problem was gone. It looks like, map service was not fully deployed.

So no need to deploy to different resource group. Probably wait for few minutes before executing LogicApps.